# Getting a particular row from database in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am working on a job site.And using Yii.I have gridview which list all the jobs posted by user,but I just want to show the jobs which are posted by a particular user.like if the user is logged in as admin then it should show only jobs posted by admin.I have tried the following things but not working.

```
 In Controller.


//codes


 public function actionViewJob() {

       $user_id = Yii::app()->session['user_id'];

        /* For User Authentication */
        if (Yii::app()->user->getId() === null)
            $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
        /* For User Authentication */

        $model = ViewJob::model()->find(array(
            'select' => array('*'), "condition" => "user_id= $user_id",
        ));

        $params = array('model' => $model,
        );

        $this->render('viewjob', $params);
    }

 function as search() in model ViewJob.


    public function search()
    {

     $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

     $criteria->compare('key_skills','Admin',true);
     return new CActiveDataProvider('viewjob', array(
       // 'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'key_skills ASC',
        ),
    ));


    }
```

What am I doing wrong here.?.Its still listing the whole data.

Comment: Does your `Yii::app()->session['user_id']` echo back the user id?Checked it?

Comment: Yes Dency...,am getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
 $model=ViewJob::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
```

Comment: Dency...Now getting the desired result in filter boxe.But still its showing all the records.

Comment: What you meant by desired result?Did u get it filtered?

Comment: Dency...Its still listing all data.I am not using filter option in cgridview,do i have to use it.?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $model = ViewJob::model()->findAll("user_id=$user_id");

 /*
 1. find() can fetch first matched row, where as findAll() fetches all matched rows in the db table
 2. "user_id=$user_id" is equals to WHERE user_id=$user_id
 */
```

**Code improvements(Yii way)**

1. Register user sessions as bellow

   ```
   Yii::app()->user->setState('user_id',$value_variable); //Set the session
   Yii::app()->user->getState('user_id'); //Get the session
   ```
2. You can use accessRules() for bellow code

   ```
    if (Yii::app()->user->getId() === null)
       $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
   ```

   Like

   ```
   public function accessRules()
   {
       return array(            
          array('allow',
           'actions' => array('viewJob'),
           'users' => array('@'),
           ----
           ---
   ```

Comment: Heraaman...still listing all the rows,do I have to include filter option in cgridview.

Comment: is there any changes in model...?