# What is wrong with the statement,in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, zii-widgets

I have a folowing code in my controller ,

```
   public function actionViewJob() {

        $user_id = Yii::app()->session['user_id'];
        /* For User Authentication */
        if (Yii::app()->user->getId() === null)
            $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
        /* For User Authentication */

         $model=ViewJob::model()->findAll(array('user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
        $params = array('model' => $model,
        );

        $this->render('viewjob', $params);
```

I am getting error /* Property "CDbCriteria.user_id" is not defined. */
but when I am using findByAttrinute its working f9,but I not getting the result,i.e its not filtering data,pls help.

view section :

```
// not posting full code //


   <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'dataProvider' =>$model->search(),  

'columns' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'title',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->title)',
                'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:90px;','class'=>'zzz'),
               // 'filter'=>'false' /* for hiding filter boxes */

         ),?>
```

Comment: Please add your `viewjob` view for the filtering.

Comment: here is my full question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008830/retreving-specific-row-from-database-in-yii/23009094?noredirect=1#comment35145848_23009094

Comment: also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961153/getting-a-particular-row-from-database-in-yii/22961606?noredirect=1#comment35069305_22961606

Comment: Hi. Please refrain from adding any more questions. I will mark all 3 as duplicates.

Comment: Also, add the `viewjob` code to this question. For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: ok,sorry..I will take care of that in future...just posted my view section,pls do have a look...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong method. You should use [`CActiveRecord::findAllByAttributes()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByAttributes-detail) instead

```
$model=ViewJob::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
```

Or if you still want to use `findAll` you should pass the attribute in as a condition:

```
$model=ViewJob::model()->findAll('user_id=:user_id',array(':user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
```

**Now for the view:**

`dataProvider` expects an instance of `CDataProvider`. `CActiveRecord::search()` returns one such instance: `CActiveDataProvider`. However, `$model` is an array not an instance of `CActiveRecord`. You have two choices here:

a) You can to edit your controller to use `$model` as a `ViewJob` instance and not an array of `ViewJob` instances:

```
public function actionViewJob() {

    $user_id = Yii::app()->session['user_id'];
    /* For User Authentication */
    if (Yii::app()->user->getId() === null)
        $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
    /* For User Authentication */

    $model= new ViewJob;
    $model->user_id = $user_id;
    $params = array('model' => $model,
    );
    ...
```

b) Replace the `$model->search()` in the view with

```
    'dataProvider' => new CArrayDataProvider($model)
```

Choice (b) is easier but it breaks conventions e.g `$model` is an array not an object. Also any filters/search functionality has to be added manually as opposed to using the default functionality provided by `CActiveRecord::search()`.

Comment: topher..but its not filtering the data...displaying all the row from table.Where I want to display only a specific row from table.how can I do that.

Comment: It worked...thanks a lot topher,...was stuck for almost two days.